# Prove conservative implies zero line integral over closed without path independence

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Based on Stewart - Calculus

---

Is this proof correct?

---

If $F$ is conservative then $\exists f$ s.t. $F = \nabla f$. If $C$ is closed, then  r(b)=r(a) hence RHS of the fundamental theorem of line integrals is zero. QED

---

[image]

Comment: You've made an one-page question, but it still absolutely unclear what you are asking! No need to attach screenshots from a book, just ask a question directly.

Comment: @CanisLupus thanks. Sorry. Edited.

Comment: Still not clear. Which two integrals on RHS? "QED?" is a question?

Comment: @CanisLupus oh lol thanks.e edited

Comment: Proof of what?.. Are you asking if an integral of a conservative field along a smooth closed path is zero? Yes. Theorem 2 proves that.

Comment: @CanisLupus well yeah that's what I was trying to confirm. Book uses path independence to prove it. I wanted to try to prove it without using path independence. thanks. Post as answer?

Comment: You can't prove that without path independence. If $C$ and $C'$ are two different paths from $\boldsymbol r (a)$ to $\boldsymbol r(b)$, and $\int_C \neq \int_{C'}$ then $C$ and $C'$ forms closed path, but $\int_C-\int_{C'}\neq 0$.

Comment: @CanisLupus Do you disagree with answerer?

Comment: Agree of course. Do you know what mean *conservative field*? *Non-conservative* field? How they are related to path-dependence and existence of a potential function? Read again your book before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{\zeta }f(r)dr = \int_{\zeta} \nabla \varphi  dr = \int_{\zeta} d \varphi = \varphi_B -\varphi_A \to \oint f(r) dr = \varphi_A - \varphi_A = 0
$$

Comment: Anonymous, do you disagree with commenter?

Comment: disagree with what? agreed or not, my answer answers your question :)